# Is it possible to deploy sketchflow wpf to PixelSense?

Tags: deployment, blend, pixelsense, sketchflow

I am using Blend + SketchFlow 2012 Preview to develop some prototypes for PixelSense. I just wonder if it is possible to deploy a sketchflow project to the PixelSense table?

Answer (score 0):

in theory, YES.
PixelSense is a "normal" computer with windows in essence. It runs WPF, so it could run sketchflow projects.
You could do a small and simple project to test, deploy it, and try to run it on the PixelSense table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the package SketchFlow project option on the file menu and copy the contents to the machine, then you can try running it to see if it works.